# How Do I Graph an SVEIAR function with the reproduction Number

Tags: graphics, mathematical-optimization, wolfram-cloud, scripting, mathematica-online

Just need help figuring out how to plot a graph of an SVEIAR model with its' reproduction number. I'm a bit confused on how to properly make a graph based off the model and reproduction number.

```
dSusceptible = q*lambda*TotalPop - (beta/TotalPop)*(h1*Infectious + epsilon1*Asymptomatic)*Susceptible - z*Susceptible - mu*Susceptible;
dVaccinated = (1 - q)*lambda*TotalPop- (beta/TotalPop)*(h2*Infectious + epsilon2*Asymptomatic)*Vaccinated + z*Susceptible - mu*Vaccinated;
dExposed = (beta/TotalPop)*(h1*Infectious + epsilon1*Asymptomatic)*Susceptible + (beta/TotalPop)*(h2*Infectious + epsilon2*Asymptomatic)*Vaccinated - tau*Exposed;
dInfectious = rho*tau*Exposed - mu*Infectious - theta1*Infectious;
dAsymptomatic = (1 - rho)*tau*Exposed - mu*Asymptomatic - theta2*Asymptomatic;
dRecovered = theta1*Infectious + theta2*Asymptomatic - mu*Recovered;

(* Basic reproduction number R0 formula *)
R0Formula = Sqrt[(beta/TotalPop*(h1*I0 + epsilon1*A0)*(rho*tau + mu + theta1))/((z + mu)*(mu + theta2)*(mu + tau)*(mu + theta1 + tau))];

lambda = 0.1;     (* Rate of new individuals entering the population per unit time *)
TotalPop = 1000;         (* Total population size *)
q = 0.8;          (* Fraction of individuals who receive the vaccine *)
beta = 0.2;       (* Infection rate *)
h1 = 0.1;         (* Proportion of infectious individuals in contact with susceptible individuals *)
epsilon1 = 0.05;  (* Proportion of asymptomatic individuals in contact with susceptible individuals *)
h2 = 0.2;         (* Proportion of infectious individuals in contact with vaccinated individuals *)
epsilon2 = 0.1;   (* Proportion of asymptomatic individuals in contact with vaccinated individuals *)
z = 0.05;         (* Rate at which individuals move from susceptible to vaccinated compartment *)
tau = 0.1;        (* Rate of movement from exposed to infectious/asymptomatic compartments *)
rho = 0.7;        (* Proportion of exposed individuals becoming infectious *)
mu = 0.01;        (* Natural death and disease-induced death rate *)
theta1 = 0.02;    (* Recovery rate of infectious individuals *)
theta2 = 0.01;    (* Recovery rate of asymptomatic individuals *)

(* Initial conditions *)
Susceptible0 = 800;
Vaccinated0 = 50;
Exposed0 = 10;
Infectious0 = 5;
Asymptomatic0 = 2;
Recovered0 = 0;
```

Comment: [Help](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/use-mathematica-find-reproduction-number-plot-solution-sveiar-epidemic-model-together-repr-q126730883) is available here.

Comment: What do you mean by "plot a graph" -- time dynamics or something else?  That is, what is on the x- and y-axes?